# Salesforce Author Apex Permission set not working

Tags: apex, permissions, appexchange

I have a requirement to implement the AppExchange app Distrubution Engine. I have intergrated the App. Now the developer(lvl 2 support) who wants to play with the app cant access the Distrubution settings.

The error poping up is

> "You do not have pemission to stop and start the scheduler. Salesforce requires the "Author Apex" permission to manage scheduled jobs. Administrator settings have been hidden.".

I have tried two methods:

1. Give Author Apex permission to the Profile “ Enterprise Support Agent” :  which the developer belongs to but this will give access to rest of the profile members too. I have checked logged in as him and found out that the “Distribution Settings” tab working properly for him.But I dont want the whole profile gets access to all Triggers and classes.
   Hence ...
2. Create a permission set for Author Access and assign it to the developer: I have created a permission set  and assigned to him. I don’t know why it’s not working & the same error pops up (Though he can create new classes after the permission set given)

Please suggest me what the error is and what would be the resolution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the user has access to all the distribution engine classes, custom objects, fields and VF pages in addition to the Author Apex perm?  There are a lot of them so it would be easy to overlook one.  Also, There are 3 permission sets that get created with Distribution Engine.  Why not assign the user the Distribution Engine Admin permission set?

- Distribution Engine Admin – Full control of the application for
  System administrators.
- Distribution Engine Manager – Access to all features except the
  Distribution Settings tab. Managers do not have the ability to stop
  and start the scheduler.
- Distribution Engine User – Access to widget, personal out of office
  and log  records for reps / agents.

Comment: I have given the user permission set "Distribution Engine Admin"  Distribution settings
 
 INFO 
You do not have pemission to stop and start the scheduler. Salesforce requires the "Author Apex" permission to manage scheduled jobs. Administrator settings have been hidden.

Comment: That permission set does not contain "Author Apex"  You need to assign that separately.       http://nc-squared.helpdocsonline.com/permissions